# How to resolve a splitting issue in python?

Tags: python

when i am trying to split with ',' from final_header_update and get the first element of the array,I dont get what i require.

```
import time
with open("master.txt", "r") as data1:
    master = data1.read().rstrip().split("\n")
with open("Security_Headers_list.txt", "r") as data2:
    for line in data2:
        num, cat = line.rstrip().split(",", 1)
        headers=num +','+','.join('1' if t in cat else '0' for t in master)
        useragent_id=str(1)
        date=time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
        final_header_update=headers+","+date+","+useragent_id
        print final_header_update
        for db_update in final_header_update:
            a=db_update.split(",")
            print a[0]
```

Output of Final_header_update is :

```
1006,1,1,1,1,1,1,08/06/2015,1
```

I got the output as:

```
1
0
0
6

1

1

1

1

1

1

0
8
/
0
6
/
2
0
1
5

1
```

Instead of just the `ID:1006`

Comment: `final_header_update` is a string and you iter over all chars in the last loop

Comment: If you just want to print the first field, why do you parse all the other fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this because you are looping over the `final_header_update`

```
for db_update in final_header_update:
```

This for loop will cause to iterate through each character in `final_header_update` which is what we don't want.

To get a more clearer picture lets consider

```
>>> final_header_update = "1006,1,1,1,1,1,1,08/06/2015,1"
>>> for db_update in final_header_update:
...     print db_update
... 
1
0
0
6
,
# And so on
```

**Solution**

Instead you can write (That is get rid of the `for` loop as such)

```
print final_header_update
a = final_header_update.split(',')
print a[0]
# Will give the output
# 1006
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `for db_update in final_header_update:`

Instead, directly do:

```
a=final_header_update.split(",")
print a[0]
```